# What is the least squares solution given a line passes through original and following points?

Tags: statistics, regression, mathematical-modeling

So I am looking for the line y=Dt through the origin that fits the data y=4 at t=1, y=5 at t=2 and y=8 at t=3.

This is what I have done so far.  I know the three equations that are supposed to be solved by least squares are:

C+D=4
C+2D=5
C+8D=3;

When plotting this on a t-y plane, we get the points (1,4), (2,5) and (8,3).  I used the

How do I make sure that these set of equations need to pass through the origin.  Does C=0 in this case?  Do I still solve it using the least squares method, which is $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b$?

It appears that the answers I am getting have a constant C and its not just y=Dt.  Can someone help me here?

Comment: That third point should be $(3,8)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C=0$. You get

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\end{pmatrix}\cdot D=\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
5\\
8\end{pmatrix}$$

Then do $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b$. Then $D$ will simply be $\frac{\sum x_i y_i}{\sum x_i^2}$.